# acts_as_taggable_on tag link conditional on context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using acts_as_taggable_on to tag posts and user profiles.  Tag records are being saved correctly with taggable_type post or profile, and context tags and interests.  Acts_as_taggable_on sends `<%= render post.tags %>` and <%= render profile.interest %> to views/acts_as_taggable_on/tags/_tag.html.erb, where the readme suggested a link_to like `<%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name) %>`.

What I'd like to do is change the path depending on either the taggable_type or the context--something like `if tag.tagging.context == 'interest' link_to tag.name, profile_tag_path(tag.name)` etc for post tags vs profile tags.

In the respective views/controllers, I can get the records correctly [filtered by context](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#dynamic-tag-contexts), I'm just having trouble changing the link path conditionally.  `tag.tagging.context` gives a no method error, `tag.taggings.each do |tag| tag.context` returns all contexts for a given tag for every time it's been used--ie, 4 prints of 'interest' and 10 prints of 'tags' if it's been used multiple times on both profiles and posts.  What I'd like is just the context for the current instance.

I'd also be happy to hear if there's another way to do this (ie, link to users/tagged/tag to return just profiles tagged with 'tag' and /tagged/tag to return just posts tagged with 'tag', etc), it just seemed like it should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful to others, I ended up iterating over each tag like so:

```
    <span class="global tags">
      <% @post.global_list.each do |tag| %>
        <span class="label label-default">
          <%= link_to tag, post_tag_path(tag) %>
        </span> 
      <% end %>
    </span>

    <span class="personal tags">
      <% @post.personal_list.each do |tag| %>
        <span class="label label-default">
          <%= link_to tag, user_tag_path(@post.user.name, tag) %>
        </span> 
      <% end %>
    </span>
```